# Multi module python logger using the name of the main module

Tags: python, logging, python-module

I have multiple python modules that I'd like to use the same logger while preserving the call hierarchy in those logs. I'd also like to do this with a logger whose name is the name of the calling module (or calling module stack). I haven't been able to work out how to get the name of the calling module except with messing with the stack trace, but that doesn't feel very pythonic.

Is this possible?

main.py

```
import logging
from sub_module import sub_log

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("main_module")

sub_log()
```

sub_module.py

```
import logging

def sub_log():
    logger = logging.getLogger(???)
    logger.info("sub_module")
```

Desired Output

```
TIME main INFO main_module
TIME main.sub_module INFO sub_module
```

Comment: Just pass the desired string as logger name. If you want `main.sub_module` to be printed, instantiate the logger with that name: `logger = logging.getLogger('main.sub_module')` etc.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to figure that out without passing a string to all of my submodules functions. Something more like, `logging.getLogger(__nameofcallstack__.__name__)`

Comment: oh, I see. How about `logging.getLogger(__module__)`?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem pythonic use the Logger Formatter:

For reference check the 
[Logging Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

main.py

```
import logging
from submodule import sub_log
from submodule2 import sub_log2


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s.%(module)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)

sub_log("test")
sub_log2("test")
```

submodule.py

```
import logging
import __main__

def sub_log(msg):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__main__.__name__)
    logger.info(msg)
```

I've created second submodule. ( same code other name)

My Results:

```
2018-10-16 20:41:23,860 __main__.submodule - INFO - test
2018-10-16 20:41:23,860 __main__.submodule2 - INFO - test
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: It definitely solves the problem if the call is one module deep, but what if submodule also calls submodule2? Then it seems like we lose the full call stack, and I wouldn't know the difference between main calling submodule2 and submodule calling submodule2 in the log file. I should've been more specific in my original question, but I didn't know you could use "__main__" like that so thanks for that!

Comment: Adding to above comment, this definitely answers the question I asked so that's on me for not being more specific.